# Simple-peer, Socket.IO, Laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, socket.io, p2p

I'm trying to create a video conferencing system using Laravel 5.3, Socket.IO and Simple-Peer. I followed this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieBtXwHvoNk and everything worked, but now I want to automatize this. I want that when two users go to this kind of link : /vide-conference/some_video_conference_id, they get connected, so the video conference can begin.

As far as I know, if I want a peer to send data to another one before they are connected, I need a signaling server. I'll use Socket.IO. But can you explain me clearly how can I have everything working with Laravel 5.3 ? I found an example here (not using laravel) : https://bl.ocks.org/adammw/d9bf021c395835427aa0, but it's talking about server side an client side code, and I don't understand because I don't know where to put the server side code, since I only have one javascript file (app.js) in my ressources/assets/js that gets compiled with gulp, so the browser can read it.

Right now, my app.js is :

```
var getUserMedia = require('getusermedia')

getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false }, function (err, stream) {
  if (err) return console.error(err)

  var Peer = require('simple-peer')
  var peer = new Peer({
    initiator: location.hash === '#init',
    trickle: false,
    stream: stream
  })

  peer.on('signal', function (data) {
    document.getElementById('yourId').value = JSON.stringify(data)
  })

  document.getElementById('connect').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var otherId = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('otherId').value)
    peer.signal(otherId)
  })

  document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var yourMessage = document.getElementById('yourMessage').value
    peer.send(yourMessage)
  })

  peer.on('data', function (data) {
    document.getElementById('messages').textContent += data + '\n'
  })

  peer.on('stream', function (stream) {
    var video = document.createElement('video')
    document.body.appendChild(video)

    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)
    video.play()
  })
})
```

And my view is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <label>Your ID:</label><br/>
    <textarea id="yourId"></textarea><br/>
    <label>Other ID:</label><br/>
    <textarea id="otherId"></textarea>
    <button id="connect">connect</button><br/>

    <label>Enter Message:</label><br/>
    <textarea id="yourMessage"></textarea>
    <button id="send">send</button>
    <pre id="messages"></pre>

    <script src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my gulpfile is:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
        .webpack('app.js');
});
```

I am a beginner in laravel and nodejs, please tell me how can I integrate socket.IO to my actual setup !

Thank you and have a nice day !

UPDATE : I tried to use socket.io-client, adding these lines of code :

```
var io = require("socket.io-client");
var client = io.connect("127.0.0.1:8080/LaravelAppFolder");
client.on('connect',function() {
    client.emit("test","foo");
});
```

But I get this error :

```
polling-xhr.js?0757:250 GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LUpVKNI 404 (Not Found)
```

Which I don't know how to solve !

UPDATE 2 : I searched for 2 days how to solve this error, but I just can't, I don't understand. Every solutions talk about server side code, http.listen, etc. And I already said that I don't understand what is this server side code. 
If you have any suggestion, it would be really appreciated!

UPDATE 3 : I finally understand what is this server side code. I created a nodejs folder in public, and I created a server.js file with this simple code :

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = require('socket.io').listen(server);

const redis =   require('redis');
const client =  redis.createClient();

server.listen(8080);

console.log("Listening.....");

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

Then i run the server in the cmd (node server.js), and everything works for server side (it says "Listening....."), but I still get this 404 error for the client, and I really have no idea why it doesn't work, since the server should solve this error.
Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score -1):

I think your front-end is being blocked by the browser. This is due to Cors.`CORS` stands for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). To know more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Solution:
use `cors` npm library to enable cors in your server

example:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = require('socket.io').listen(server);

//use cors as a middleware
app.use(cors())

//use socket connection

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('Made Connection',socket.id);
});

//listen to server
server.listen(8080);
```

Source code :
https://github.com/vj-abishek/facetime-server